# Wash adsorbed protein without destroying Biotin-Avidin-Mechanism

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, protein-binding

I am looking for reliable protocols to wash protein (e.g. Fibronectin) adsorbed onto glass surfaces. According to Protein immobilization literature, people usually use 1% SDS and some incubation time. For me this did not work.

Furthermore, the removal step should not destroy an existing avidin-biotin-mechanism.

Does anyone have experience with that? Or is there some kind of standard protocol, which I am missing?

---

**More detailed process:**
I have a quartz coverslip with covalently bound Biotin on some surface area. First I add Avidin (Sigma, 10µg/ml), then biotinylated human plasma Fibronectin (Sigma, 10µg/ml). Now I want to wash adsorbed Avidin/Fibronectin, so I have free "glass" area. This is important for me.

For some reason changing the system is not an option for me.

Comment: SDS shouldn't appreciably disrupt avidin-biotin interactions. The complex is extremely stable.

Comment: @canadianer SDS *will* disrupt the avidin-biotin bond at high enough concentrations. 1% is rather high (similar to Laemmli sample buffer), so that may be why the OP's experiment didn't work.

Comment: Can you explain what *this did not work* means in greater detail?

Comment: @MattDMo I have put streptavidin in SDS-PAGE loading buffer (2% SDS) and run it in an SDS-PAGE gel with only negligible denaturation. [This paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/15366934/) has similar, and more formal, findings. I've also washed streptavidin conjugated chromatography columns with SDS without any leakage of the target protein. That said, it's hard to say if the SDS is or is not affecting the experiment. It would help if the OP gave the protocol and explained why it didn't work.

Comment: @canadianer that's really interesting. Did you add a reducing agent (DTT, BME) and/or boil the sample?

Comment: @MattDMo I don't remember if I had a reducing agent or not. No boiling though. Boiling + SDS = unfolding

Comment: @canadianer Let's continue this in the Biology [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1997/the-biosphere) - it's kind of off-topic here.

Comment: @MattDMo Sure..

Comment: Sorry guys, time shift. I'll explain in more detail as soon as I'm back on the PC. Avidin biotin was totally stable with sds 1% (actually I used laemmli, 2hrs incubation at 4°C). But none of the adsorbed protein was washed away.

Comment: Do you want to wash off the fibronectin?

Comment: yes, except the avidin-linked fibronectins.